# Dictionary<string, object> to object

Tags: c#, object, dictionary

What the best way convert this dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, object> person = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                            person.Add("ID", 1);
                            person.Add("Name", "Alex");
```

to object:

```
public class Person
{
public int ID{get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

?

Comment: check out this link it may help answer your question http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/05/03/Anonymous-type-to-dictionary-using-DynamicMethod.aspx

Comment: I want return object from Select database query.

Comment: I think there is a misconception here on the Dictionary class. You seem to make two different elements of the dictionary corresponding to one semantic object. What you need seems to be a Dictionary object, having an int mapping to a Person object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to do this for any object in general, you could use reflection.  Assuming the values in the dictionary are the appropriate type and requires no conversion:

```
static T GetObject<T>(Dictionary<string, object> dict)
    where T : new()
{
    var obj = new T();
    foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        var args = new object[1];
        var setter = property.GetSetMethod(); // property has a public setter
        if (setter != null && dict.TryGetValue(property.Name, out args[0]))
            setter.Invoke(obj, args);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Then to use it:

```
var alexDict = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "ID", 1 },
    { "Name", "Alex" },
};
var alexPerson = GetObject<Person>(alexDict);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my suggestion:

```
var newPerson = new Person 
    { 
        ID = (int)person["ID"],
        Name = person["Name"].ToString()
    };
```

This has no error handling and is assuming that the fields exists in the dictionary and are filled with valid values!

Answer (score 0):

```
Person myPerson = new Person();
myPerson.ID = (int)person["ID"];
myPerson.Name = (string)person["Name"];
```

Provides no error checking with the int cast.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way:

```
var person = new Person
{
    Id = (int)dict["ID"],
    Name = (string)dict["Name"]
}
```

The generic way: use reflection.